# Resources about critiques of Strong Rule Utilitarism

Tags: reference-request

I would like to read critiques against Strong Rule Utilitarianism[1], but avoiding those that only treat it as another problematic Deontological Moral Theory.

[1]: Strong Rule Utilitarianism means: Use Utilitarianism first principle to generate rules and always follows the rules that this creates with no exceptions.

Comment: Hello, Dedekind Hilbert, and welcome to PSE. But now, your question risks being closed because it needs more detail. What do you mean by 'strong' rule utilitarianism ? How does it connect with ontology ? It would help if you clarified these points.

Comment: 'Use Utilitarianism first principle to generate rules and always follows the rules that this creates with no exceptions.' Please explain what you take Utilitarianism's 'first principle' to be.